# Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a random word generator that will pull a word at random from a list every 7 seconds.

My button to stop this word generator returns the 1004 error and the Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed.

Below are the codes for both buttons. Stop macro is from the [OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnTime) page on Microsoft

```
Sub RandoWord()


Dim rw As Long
    rw = [RandBetween(2,1526)]
   Cells(3, 4) = Cells(rw, 1)
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:07"), "RandoWord"


    
End Sub

Sub StopRandoWord()
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:07"), _
 Procedure:="RandoWord", Schedule:=False
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the exact time of the next run if you want to cancel it.

```vb
Dim NextRun

Sub RandoWord()
    Dim rw As Long
    
    rw = [RandBetween(2,1526)]
    Cells(3, 4) = Cells(rw, 1) 'really needs a specific worksheet...
    NextRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:07")
    Application.OnTime NextRun, "RandoWord"

End Sub

Sub StopRandoWord()
    If NextRun>0 Then
        Application.OnTime NextRun, Procedure:="RandoWord", Schedule:=False
        NextRun = 0  
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Williams! There's always just one more thing, isn't there?